# Is using SUM on multiple columns allowed in general SQL?

Tags: mysql

I had a question in my GATE Mock Test Paper that was as follows:

> Which of the following can appear in position marked as [..]?
>
> "Select [..] from R group by A, B"
>
> I. SUM(C+D)
>
> II. A, Min(C)
>
> III. A,B, Min(C)

I answered all of the above, but my friends and answer key stated that only II and III are correct. I ran the query on mysql with no problem, and saw this code listed on few websites as well.

So is this query valid for general SQL, or it is implemented only by certain applications such as MySQL?

Comment: All variants are valid. Documentation claims that the argument of SUM() is expression. Of course, valid expression. The expression C+D is valid (if fields with those names exists). So my friends and answer key makes a mistake. **PS.** *General SQL* - what do you mean?

Comment: By general I meant standard SQL syntax.. some of them vary from server to server, don't they?

Comment: *By general I meant standard SQL syntax* Not exists. There are SQL standards (SQL-89, SQL-92, etc.) - if you tell about it, you must specify the standard we speak about.

Comment: Run it on MySQL 8.0; it gets pickier about `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: I have no idea what 'GATE Mock Test Paper' is, or if that's supposed to have a bearing on the answer, so fwiw ...

As others have pointed out, technically all of the answers could be true ... though this will depend on the RDBMS (ie, flavor of SQL) as well as any configs/settings.

---

If the intention is to pick answers that are ANSI compliant, then I'd say 'III' is the correct answer since all non-aggregates should be part of the `group by`.  Then again, if you start looking at some of the nitty-gritty ANSI details you'll find this requirement can sometimes be relaxed.

As you'll find out, most RDBMS products don't enforce such a strict standard: all non-aggregates being a member of the `group by` clause

---

As Michael Kutz has mentioned, without 'A' and/or 'B' in the select/projection list, answers 'I' and 'II' will provide some confusing answers. [And if you ever find yourself working in a real world RDBMS environment you'll find developers writing these types of queries all the time, but then not being able to describe what it is they're asking for let alone being able to explain the results they end up with.]

Again, answer 'III' is the only one I'd say can be clearly explained ... what I'm looking for ... the results I end up with.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

All of them are valid.  However, I and II are logical nonsense.

## Expected Results

For every `A,B` combination, you will get 1 row irregardless of what columns/aggregates are listed in the `SELECT` clause.
If you have 100 distinct combinations of `A,B`, I expect your result to show 100 rows for `I`,`II`, and `III`.

## Logic

Answer `I` will show a series of values.  You will have no idea which values are for which `A,B` combination because `A` and `B` are not part of your `SELECT` statement.
Because you don't have an `ORDER BY` clause, you can make no assumptions about which row matches to which combination of `A,B`.

Answer `II` will show a series of values for each distinct value of `A`.  You will have no idea which values are for which `A,B` combination because `B` is not part of your `SELECT` statement.
Because you don't have an `ORDER BY` clause, you can make no assumptions about which row matches to which combination of `A,B`.

Answer III will show a series of values for each distinct combination of `A,B`.

## Conclusion

From a syntax stand point, they are all valid.

From a logical stand point, only III is valid.

Comment: *However, I and II are logical nonsense.* Assume the query in question is a subquery used to obtain minimal/maximal value of this sum for to use in WHERE/HAVING clause... values A and B are not needed in variant 1, is it? And some the same for variant 2. So not 'are' but 'may be' only.